# Running total not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a query taken from Itzik Ben-Gan's book "T-SQL Querying" but doesn't seem to work against my 2012 db - although I think there must be a typo in the script:

```
-- Isolate top waits
WITH Waits AS
(
  SELECT    wait_type,
            wait_time_s = wait_time_ms / 1000.,
            pct     = 100. * wait_time_ms / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER(),
            rn      = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC)
  FROM      sys.dm_os_wait_stats o
  WHERE     wait_type NOT LIKE '%SLEEP%'
  -- filter out additional irrelevant waits
)
SELECT  W1.wait_type, 
        CAST(W1.wait_time_s AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS wait_time_s,
        CAST(W1.pct AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS pct--,
        CAST(SUM(W2.pct) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS running_pct --<<XXX
FROM    Waits AS W1
        JOIN Waits AS W2 --<<XXX
         ON W2.rn <= W1.rn --<<XXX
GROUP BY W1.rn, W1.wait_type, W1.wait_time_s, W1.pct
HAVING  SUM(W2.pct) - W1.pct < 90 -- percentage threshold  --<<XXX
ORDER BY W1.rn;
GO
```

If I comment out the sections marked `XXX` then it returns results that I'd expect:

[image]

If I run the whole query it results in the following with duplicates and an incorrect column `running_pct`:

[image]

How do I fix this?
I tried adding `AND W2.wait_type <> W1.wait_type` into the `ON` clause - this helps but seems to then discard `wait_type` : `CXPACKET`

---

**EDIT**

Should he have `W1.rn` in the `GROUP BY` section ?

Comment: It seems you are right. What use is `GROUP BY W1.run` when it is not in the output of the query?

Comment: @shahkalpesh any answers on an obvious fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Itzik and he kindly replied with the below e-mail - which is correct:

*Hi Jason,*

*I’m not sure what you mean by the query not working for you.
First, it seems like your query is a modified version of what I provided in the book. Here’s the one from the book, and it works just fine for me:*

```
WITH Waits AS
(
  SELECT
    wait_type,
    wait_time_ms / 1000. AS wait_time_s,
    100. * wait_time_ms / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER() AS pct,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC) AS rn,
    100. * signal_wait_time_ms / wait_time_ms as signal_pct
  FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
  WHERE wait_time_ms > 0
    AND wait_type NOT LIKE N'%SLEEP%'
)
SELECT
  W1.wait_type,
  CAST(W1.wait_time_s AS NUMERIC(12, 2)) AS wait_time_s,
  CAST(W1.pct AS NUMERIC(5, 2)) AS pct,
  CAST(SUM(W2.pct) AS NUMERIC(5, 2)) AS running_pct,
  CAST(W1.signal_pct AS NUMERIC(5, 2)) AS signal_pct
FROM Waits AS W1
  JOIN Waits AS W2
    ON W2.rn <= W1.rn
GROUP BY W1.rn, W1.wait_type, W1.wait_time_s, W1.pct, W1.signal_pct
HAVING SUM(W2.pct) - W1.pct < 90 -- percentage threshold
    OR W1.rn <= 5
ORDER BY W1.rn;
GO
```

*As for your version, there seems to be a misplaced line comment specifier (two dashes) right after AS pct (see below highlighted part):*

```
WITH Waits AS
(
  SELECT    wait_type,
            wait_time_s = wait_time_ms / 1000.,
            pct     = 100. * wait_time_ms / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER(),
            rn      = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC)
  FROM      sys.dm_os_wait_stats o
  WHERE     wait_type NOT LIKE '%SLEEP%'
  -- filter out additional irrelevant waits
)
SELECT  W1.wait_type,
        CAST(W1.wait_time_s AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS wait_time_s,
        CAST(W1.pct AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS pct--,
        CAST(SUM(W2.pct) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS running_pct --<<XXX
FROM    Waits AS W1
        JOIN Waits AS W2 --<<XXX
         ON W2.rn <= W1.rn --<<XXX
GROUP BY W1.rn, W1.wait_type, W1.wait_time_s, W1.pct
HAVING  SUM(W2.pct) - W1.pct < 90 -- percentage threshold  --<<XXX
ORDER BY W1.rn;
```

*Once I remove it, the query seems to run fine:*

```
WITH Waits AS
(
  SELECT    wait_type,
            wait_time_s = wait_time_ms / 1000.,
            pct     = 100. * wait_time_ms / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER(),
            rn      = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC)
  FROM      sys.dm_os_wait_stats o
  WHERE     wait_type NOT LIKE '%SLEEP%'
  -- filter out additional irrelevant waits
)
SELECT  W1.wait_type,
        CAST(W1.wait_time_s AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS wait_time_s,
        CAST(W1.pct AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS pct,
        CAST(SUM(W2.pct) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS running_pct --<<XXX
FROM    Waits AS W1
        JOIN Waits AS W2 --<<XXX
         ON W2.rn <= W1.rn --<<XXX
GROUP BY W1.rn, W1.wait_type, W1.wait_time_s, W1.pct
HAVING  SUM(W2.pct) - W1.pct < 90 -- percentage threshold  --<<XXX
ORDER BY W1.rn;
```

*If it still doesn’t run for you, let me know what’s the error you’re getting.*

*Cheers,
Itzik*